# Flask endpoint always returns response with 500

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have the following endpoint which makes ssh connection to a server and copies some files onto it.

```
@upgrade_api.route("/take_copy_postgres_backup", methods=['POST'])
def take_copy_postgres_backup():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.get_json()

            hostname = data['hostname']
            username = data['username']
            password = data['password']
            scp_path = data['scp_path']
            ssh_port = data['ssh_port'] or 22

            ssh = SSHClient()
            ssh.load_system_host_keys()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(hostname=hostname, port=ssh_port, username=username, password=password, compress=True)

        // Open a file and copy to server over scp

        return Response('Success', 200)
    except ssh_exception.BadHostKeyException as e:
        logger.error(e)
        return Response('Cannot verify SSH server host key', 404)
    except ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as e:
        logger.error(e)
        return Response(response='Authentication for SSH server failed', status=401)
    except ssh_exception.SSHException as e:
        logger.error(e)
        return Response('SSH to the server failed for some reason', 500)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
        return Response('Internal Server Error', 500)
    finally:

        //Close the file
```

On providing invalid username and/or password I am expecting that `AuthenticationException` will be handled and a response with 401 status code will be returned. However on hitting the endpoint using curl or postman I always get the following response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Even if the `AuthenticationException` is handled and logged I still get `500 - Internal Server Error`.

I tried removing the generic exception at the end and running again and still getting the same response. I also tried running a debugger but cant seem to find where the response is actually being sent.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: your finally block is stopping the return, then returning None which causes a 500. Remove your finally block or put some logic in it.

Comment: @nathan.medz Yes thanks for the help. I dont know what I was thinking. Can you write an answer so that I can accept it?